# Method not allowed http exception laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel, I tried to make a simple login form, but i am getting 'method not allowed' http exception message, can anyone help me to solve this ? thank you

my form is :

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@doLogin', 'method' => 'post' , 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form-horizontal loginFrm')) }}
          <div class="control-group">                               
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
        <button type="submit" name="signin" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

my controller :

```
public function doLogin()
{

    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required', 
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' 
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('index')->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::except('password')); 
    } else {
        $userdata = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {


            return Redirect::to('index');

        } else {      
            return Redirect::to('index');
        }
    }

}
```

my routes :

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('index');
});
Route::post('index', 'HomeController@doLogin');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not having `get` route for `index` on which you are redirecting the user after login. 
Change this in your **routes.php**

```
Route::get('/index', function(){return View::make('index');});
```

and you are good.

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects

Comment: thanks for the help, but if i change that on my routes.php, i get another error, it is not found http excepton || Update : index is the name of blade on my view folder(index.blade.php) that is where my form is located.

Comment: Dude, you can't pass `view` in `Redirect::to('route')` method.

Comment: i change Redirect::to('index') to Redirect::to('/') and it works, thanks !

Comment: @Janotama please accept and upvote my answer if it helped.